# Ansible - wait for user to key in value for interactive scripts on remote machine

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like the ansible to wait for my input in the command line for interactive script running in remote machine.  "Expect" will not suite my requirement as the interactive questions keep changing.

eg
xxx.pl
This must be the user which is running service. [root:root]': y  ----> i should be allowed to change in realtime
handling utilities? [/usr/bin]: y   ---> same with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Ansible.

Ansible packs all task scripts/parameters before sending it for execution to remote host and there is no way (as of Ansible 2.4) to get any feedback during task execution – only final result of task.

Comment: I wonder... if you called a script, which would execute the proper script in a separate`screen` session, grabbed its output (redirect standard output to a file?), returned the proper script's question as its output, then Ansible would prompt user, and the next task would run another script to reconnect to the `screen` session and pass user's value...

Comment: The second task (reconnecting) would have to be an Expect module or a script calling `expect`.

Comment: @techraf theoretically this is possible... but as we both know, Ansible playbooks should have no human interaction :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone (like myself) curious about this and landing on this page per google. Looks as if it's now possible through the [prompts feature](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)! (I don't think it's even so much as a built-in module. It seems like it's just built-in. Can't find it under [Ansible.Builtin Plugin Index](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/index.html#plugin-index). It's just under [Playbook Advanced Features](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_special_topics.html).