# how to get prompts from execution of playbook

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook. Which contains script and that runs on windows machine.
That script asks for some input at middle of execution. How to capture that prompt and display that prompt from ansible?

Comment: can you share some code or picture of the workflow or some references whats going on in that playbook and how that the prompt look like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible - wait for user to key in value for interactive scripts on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193849/ansible-wait-for-user-to-key-in-value-for-interactive-scripts-on-remote-machin)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for Ansible to prompt in the middle of a playbook.
This is intentional in the design. What you can do is [prompt at the beginning of a playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html) to give a variable. I haven't seen this a lot though, people usually use the Ansible vault if they have secrets they don't want in the playbook.

The best thing to do would be to give the values to your script with parameters. That would be the safest. If not you can always [try responding through the prompts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) but I would discourage that.